# Node.js script request using HTTP Range header is resulting in more bytes than requested.

Tags: node.js, http, download, chunks, request-promise

I am attempting to write a Node.js script that takes in a URL (to download 
a file) specified through the command line. Using the HTTP Range request header the script downloads the file in a configurable number of chunks and chunk size and then writes to an output file in the correct Byte order.

Currently looking to achieve this with 2 chunks of 1 MiB (1,048,576 Bytes) for a total of 2 MiB (2,097,152 B).

Current issue I am running into either in execution or just my understanding is that my script is writing ~ 1,800,000 Bytes for each request resulting in a total of 3,764,942 Bytes. Not sure where those extra Bytes are coming from?

Is this due to a mistake I missed in this script or overhead from the request library used maybe or am I missing something about Mib to Bytes conversion?

- Contents of file are largely irrelevant right now so long as correct number of Bytes are in correct order.
- Curling the test URL with the range header set to 1MiB chunks and then appending to a file results in closer to expected number of total Bytes. `curl 'https://eloquentjavascript.net/Eloquent_JavaScript.pdf' -i -H "Range: bytes=0-2097152"` => 2097435 B file
- I am running this command in terminal `node index.js --url='https://eloquentjavascript.net/Eloquent_JavaScript.pdf' --file='newfile.txt' --chunks 2`
- Using Node v10.12.0, minimist v1.2.0, and request-promise v4.2.2

### **Entire script below:**

```
'use strict';

const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2), {
    default: {
        file: 'output.txt',
        MiB: 1,
        chunks: 4
    }
});
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request-promise');

// Source URL must be specified through command line option.
if (!argv.url) throw Error('Source URL is required!');

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: argv.url
}

const determineChunkRange = (step) => {
    // 1 Mib = 1,048,576 B.
    // Only 1 MiB chunks are downloaded.
    const chunkSize = argv.MiB * 1048576;
    const startOfRange = step === 0 ? 0 + ((chunkSize * step)) : 1 + ((chunkSize * step));
    const endOfRange = startOfRange + chunkSize;

    return {'Range': `bytes=${startOfRange}-${endOfRange}`}
}

const getOptions = (step) => {
    options.headers = determineChunkRange(step);

    return options;
}

const addDataToFile = (data) => {
    try {
        fs.appendFileSync(argv.file, data);
        console.log("Data written to file.");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Error appending to ${argv.file}`, err);
    }
}

// Create or Replace file with specific filename.
fs.writeFileSync(argv.file, '');
console.log("Successfully created new file.");

// Make specified number of requests.
for (let i = 0; i < argv.chunks; i++) {
    const options = getOptions(i);

    // make request to specified URL.
    request(options)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(i, options)
            addDataToFile(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(`Error making request to ${argv.url}`, error)
        });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the response contain only the file? log  the response before writing it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you add the whole response object, not it's content/body.

You can use the response's `data` event to get content and then append it to the file.